# TypeError : Cannot assign to read only property '_id' of { ... }

Tags: node.js, mongodb, post, mongodb-query, node-webkit

I am trying to acquire a keyboard string and save it in mongoDB, using the `POST` method. The server is started, but I can not write the input into the database, because the console returns the following error:

> `TypeError : Cannot assign to read-only property '_id' of {the text that I entered through html page}.`

I started from very little to work with nodejs and mongodb, I need help ... Thanks for your attention :)

**server.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var assert = require('assert');

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/data'; 

// Use connect method to connect to the Server

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

 assert.equal(null, err);
 console.log("Connected correctly to server");

 app.listen(3000, function() {

  console.log('listening on 3000');

  app.get('/index.html', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
  });

  app.post('/process_post', function(req, res){

  response={r:req.body.s};  

  var risp=JSON.stringify(response);  

  res.end(risp);

  console.log("Insert : "+risp); 

    //"text" is an existing collection of mongodb "data" locally

  var collection = db.collection('text'); 

    collection.insert(risp); 

  }); 

 }); 

db.close();

});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/process_post" method = "POST">
         Input: <input "text" name=s >  <br>

         <button type = "submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because you are trying to add a string to the database. You should insert the object. Instead of inserting `risp`, try inserting the `response` var and see if it works. Also notice that the insert is asynchronous, so consider adding a callback function. See [this example](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/insert/#insert-a-document), the method is different but the logic should be the same.

Comment: Doing this does not get more previous error but the insertion process is not completed ... that is, the server runs but never complete the POST. Do not insert anything into the database, "every time" that use the submit print on the screen with `console.log ( "Insert:" + resp);` the following line: "Insert: [object Obeject].

If I consider the line of code: `res.end (resp);` I get the following error: TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer.

I feel a little desperate ..

Comment: response** not resp